# Community Moderator election banner missing from main site

Tags: support, status-completed, election

Currently, the main site is missing the banner link to the moderator election page, though the Meta site still has the banner functioning correctly.

Comment: not a bug, by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has an auto-expire and we cannot set it for more than 48 hs.

I re-enabled it for another 2 days.

Comment: Excellent. (15)

Comment: Pst. Give it another kick!